# How to build relationship map?

Tags: graphql

I like GraphQL and another libraries around GraphQL. I like GraphQL tools. But I found that I need a relation map. I thought that such tool had to exist. But I have not found. Does it exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking for a visual representation of relations, you could use GraphQL introspection to achieve this. Take a look on GraphQL Voyager:

**Demo:**
https://apis.guru/graphql-voyager/

Copy the introspection query, paste and run it on your GraphQL API endpoint.Copy the results into GraphQL Voyager. You should get a nice visual representation of your data relations available through your GraphQL API.

**Github:**
https://github.com/APIs-guru/graphql-voyager

Comment: Voyager author here :) Thanks @lars-emil-christensen for answering!
Feel free to ask any questions.